# Serving New Data With Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

There may already by an answer to this question but I was unable to find it.

Let's say I have a Node.js webpage doing somewhat time-consuming API calls and computations:

```
var request = require('request'),
    Promise = require('es6-promise').Promise,
    is_open = require('./is_open');

// Fetch the name of every eatery
var api_url = 'url of some api';
request(api_url, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    // Good to go!
    var results = JSON.parse(body).events;
    results.(function (result) {
      // This line makes its own set of API calls
      is_open(result
        .then(function (output) {
          console.log(output);
          if (output == false) {
            console.log('CLOSED\n');
          } else {
            console.log(output);
            console.log();
          }
        })
        .catch(console.error);
    });
  } else {
    console.log('Returned an unknown error.');
    console.log(error);
    console.log(response);
    console.log(body);
  }
});
```

(I haven't yet created an actual web server, I'm just running the app locally through the command line.)

I want the web server to serve a loading page first to every user. Then, once the API calls are complete and the data is ready, it should send that data in a new webpage to the same user.

The reason I think there's an issue is because in order to serve a webpage, you must end with:

```
res.end();
```

Therefore ending the connection to that specific user.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `var Promise = Promise   = required(...)`?

Comment: You should perhaps not use the same variable name as a class name, e.g., `Promise = new Promise()`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Actually the NPM package readme recommends that I do, since each time I create a new promise the syntax would be `var new_promise = new Promise(…)` - see https://www.npmjs.org/package/es6-promise

Comment: Right, sorry, I'm thinking of the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You must conceptually separate static content from dynamic content (later you will serve static with nginx or apache leaving only dynamic to node)
2. The best solution to your "problem" is to make the first webpage ask the data via AJAX once loaded. Ideally, your node app will return JSON to an ajax query from the first page, and js on the page will format the result creating DOM nodes.